# Объекты разной ширины

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос, задача сделать некое подобие таблицы с данными, но количество столбцов должно зависеть от ширины содержимого, вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При помощи каких компонентов это можно сделать и как? И если можно пример

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет FlexboxLayout , применры можно посмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Comment: @Z.John, да подошло, спасибо)

Comment: также можете ещё посмотреть на [constraintlayout-flow-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874011/constraintlayout-flow-helper-example)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать FlexboxLayout.

Добавляем зависимость в Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
```

Добавляем `FlexboxLayout` в макет:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/type"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MarkAndModel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent>
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Инициализируем `FlexboxLayout`:

```
flexboxLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.type);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(20,10,20,10);
TextView textView = new TextView(flexboxLayout.getContext());
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
textView.setText(data[i]);
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_panel);
textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textView.setTextSize(16);
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
flexboxLayout.addView(textView);
```